# Nuxt: ServerMiddleware should expose a handle undefined

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, servermiddleware

I am registering a serverMiddleware using a custom module like this in **module.js** file

```
const middleware = require('./utils');
this.nuxt.hook('render:setupMiddleware', app => {
        this.addServerMiddleware(middleware(app));
      })
```

Here **middleware** function is imported from a separate file **utils/index.js** which looks like this

```
module.exports = function(app){
app.use('/test', (req, res, next) => {
  /*doing some stuff here*/
});
}
```

While running the application it gives the error

```
ServerMiddleware should expose a handle: undefined
```

If i register **utils/index.js** file using **nuxt.config.js** file like this then it works fine

```
serverMiddleware: [
    'custome_module/utils/index',
  ],
```

Please suggest how it can be registered using module.js file.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error ServerMiddleware should expose a handle nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63547656/error-servermiddleware-should-expose-a-handle-nuxt)